# Scala handling missing with nested Optionals

Tags: scala

Let's say I have an object `A`, which may have an `Option` `B`, which may also reference another optional object `C` (nested optionals)

I've seen a couple of ways of accessing `C`, like the for-comprehension, pattern matching or `flatMap` which all do look nice. But what if I have to return some kind of error message or throw an exception if `B` or `C` is missing or provide a message like `cannot execute because B is missing` or `C not set`? I can only fall back to (mocking):

```
if(a.b.isDefined)
{
   if(a.b.c.isDefined)
   {
           //do work
   }
   else throw new Exception1 //or call something other
}
else throw new OtherException //or do something other
```

How could I handle in a functional or more fluent way?

Comment: Have you considered using `Either[A, B]` for the inner types?

Comment: Actually no. I'm using Java 8 a bit more so I'm kinda influenced by the Optional. In which way exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B`:

```
  a.b.getOrElse(throw new OtherException).c.getOrElse(throw new Exception1)
```

It is good idea with `implicit` wrapper and `AnyVal` optimization (described before), but your code becomes less readable. I think more preferable to use existing method instead of to write wrappers every time.

About `map`, It is really useless here. It has sense if you don't need to throw an `Exception`.

Comment: I like your answer a bit better than @Lee's, only because it is more readable. Intuitively this is not something I would choose an implicit, although it looks coo.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a method to convert an `Option` into a `Try` and fail if the value is none e.g.

```
implicit class OptionWrapper[T](val o: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def tryGet(e: => Throwable): Try[T] = o match {
        case Some(x) => Success(x)
        case None => Failure(e)
    }   
}
```

then you can do

```
a.b.tryGet(new OtherException).flatMap(_.tryGet(new Exception1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of convert Option to something else I would do it like this:

```
    def getC(a: A) = a.b.map { b1 =>
        b1.c.getOrElse {
            throw new UndefinedC
        }
    }.getOrElse {
        throw new UndefinedB
    }
```

In short if **b** is defined then map will let you use it and then you can use getOrElse on **c** to return it or throw an exception if not. 
The last getOrElse apply to **b** so if map returns an instance of **c** it will return it otherwise if **b** is undefined it will let you throw an exception.

I've wrote a quick test using Scalatest to prove it:

```
import org.scalatest._

class TestClass extends FlatSpec with Matchers with OptionValues with Inside with Inspectors {
    case class C( name: String ) {
        def echo = name
    }

    case class B( c: Option[C] )

    case class A( b: Option[B] )

    class UndefinedB extends Exception
    class UndefinedC extends Exception

    def getC( a: A ) = {
        a.b.map { b1 =>
            b1.c.getOrElse {
                throw new UndefinedC
            }
        }.getOrElse {
            throw new UndefinedB
        }
    }

    "With both b and c defined c.echo" should "be equal to the c.name value" in {
         val c = new C( name = "Alessandro" )
         val b = new B( Some( c ) )
         val a = new A( Some( b ) )

         assert( getC(a).echo.equals( "Alessandro" ) )
    }

    "With only b defined" should "throw UndefinedC" in {
        val c = new C( name = "Alessandro" )
        val b = new B( None )
        val a = new A( Some( b ) )

        intercept[UndefinedC] { getC(a).echo.equals( "Alessandro" ) }
    }

    "With only b not defined" should "throw UndefinedB" in {
        val c = new C( name = "Alessandro" )
        val b = new B( Some( c ) )
        val a = new A( None )

        intercept[UndefinedB] { getC(a).echo.equals( "Alessandro" ) }
    }
}
```

Edit:
By the way, Alexandr Dorokhin answer has less boilerplate than mine and if you use it in the tests they will pass.

Comment: Kudos for the TDD approach :)